# Can I make an area chart which bounds defined between two lines with Google Charts library?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I need to implement the following chart and right now we're using Google Chart library and most close chart which I find to this is [Area Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart). The problem that Area Chart define an area between axis X and Line. In my case, I need to define an area between 2 lines. Can it be done with Google Chart library?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a stacked area chart, with the bottom stack color set to transparent.

see following working snippet,
here, I draw a line, then use a data view to draw the area around it.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [1, 115],
    [2, 116],
    [3, 117],
    [4, 118],
    [5, 119],
    [6, 125],
    [7, 135],
    [8, 145],
    [9, 142],
    [10, 140],
    [11, 136],
    [12, 128],
    [13, 120],
    [14, 118],
    [15, 117],
    [16, 116],
    [17, 112],
    [18, 110],
    [19, 110],
    [20, 109],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1) - 60;
    },
    type: 'number',
    label: 'bottom'
  }, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1);
    },
    type: 'number',
    label: 'top'
  }]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['blue', 'transparent', 'blue'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    height: 400,
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      0: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 4,
        type: 'line'
      },
      1: {
        enableInteractivity: false,
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
      2: {
        enableInteractivity: false,
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```